# What is the difference in gzip compression levels?

Tags: linux, compression, gzip

Have been using gzip for a few years and usually I always `gzip -9` out of habit as it is the highest level of compression. I understand that lower levels means less compression but quicker compress rate.

What is the real difference between the levels of compression?

From what I have read regarding DEFLATE (what gzip uses), the levels specify the amount of time the algorithm spends finding repetition in bytes and encoding the data properly. I don't quite understand how this would differ between one pass of a file or multiple passes of a file. Wouldn't all bytes that are replicated be compressed on the first pass (all the repetition removed)?

Comment: What makes you think it's doing "multiple passes"?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 That is a valid point, limited knowledge of compression so perhaps I misread something somewhere to give me that idea. Is it not doing multiple passes?

Comment: Short answer: compression levels affects buffer size.
See [How do the different compression levels of gzip differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44895609/how-do-the-different-compression-levels-of-gzip-differ)